# how to padded batch in dataset for each dimension padding to max length of all dimensions

Tags: tensorflow

I already know dataset provide padded_batch function to padded batch as below:

```
padded_batch(
    batch_size,
    padded_shapes,
    padding_values=None
)
```

I want to padding each dimension in my batch to the max length of all dimensions, but the above function can't achieve this.

for example:

the element in my dataset is as below:

```
([],      [5,5,5,5,5])

([1],     [6,6,6,6,6,6])

([2,2],   [7,7,7,7,7,7,7])

([3,3,3], [8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8])

what I want after padding is 

([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],      [5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0])

([1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],      [6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0))

([2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],      [7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0])

([3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0],      [8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8])
```

if I apply the function like this:

```
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(
            4, 
            padded_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([None]), 
            tf.TensorShape([None]))                            
          )
```

I got the result as below:

```
([0,0,0],      [5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0])

([1,0,0],      [6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0))

([2,2,0],      [7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0])

([3,3,3],      [8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8])
```

this is not what I wanted, I am struggling with this problem for a long time, can any one help me?

Comment: Do you know the maximum length in advance? In which case you could set `padded_shapes` to that explicitly. The issue is that this is a streaming API, so there's no way for the `Dataset` to know the maximum length across future batches. You could iterate over the whole dataset and compute the maximum length, then pass that in to future `padded_batch` calls, or keep a streaming maximum. Why do you need a consistent padded length?

Comment: Yes, I can get the maximum length of the whole dataset, but I want to padded each batch to the maximum length in that batch not the  whole dataset,  batching and padding is done autamtically by `padded_batch(..)`,  no way to get the maximum length  of each batch

Comment: So you're fine with the behavior, you just want to get the padded length? You can get the shape as an integer Tensor with [tf.shape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape).